# How to check whether sqlite database is attached or not?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am using sqlite to store my data. I have two databases. In my application, each time a new request comes, I am attaching first db to second db. The problem is, if two request come it is showing the db already in use (it is trying to attach twice with same alias name 'db'). I want to know if there is any way to check whether a database is attached or not?

Comment: Please update your question/tags with the language you are using :)

Comment: Would you please show some code so that we know what you are doing?

Comment: I am executing Attach database statement(Attach Database expr to dbname") to attach the databases. The problem is second time when I execute this query I am getting error "db is already in use". So, I want to check whether database is already attached or not. If it is attached then return otherwise attach the database

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
PRAGMA database_list;
```

outputs a resultset with full list of available databases.  The first column is database name, the second is database file (empty if it is not associated with file). The primary database is always named `main`, temporary db is always `temp`.

```
sqlite> attach "foo.db" as foo;
sqlite> pragma database_list;
0|main|
2|foo|/Users/me/tmp/foo.db
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are reusing the same connection to the database for multiple requests. Because databases are [attached](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) to the connection object, attaching fails for the second or further requests with the same connection. The solution I think is thus to attach the database immediately after a new connection is made, and not each time a request is received.